# Регулярное выражение: пять цифр, не все одинаковые

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Условие, что должны проходить 5 цифр, но не одинаковые подряд. Например, 12345, 223341,44441, но не 00000, 11111 и т.д.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что такое можно сделать с помощью регулярного выражения

Comment: Это почему? Это кажется легчайшим, но я не знаком достаточно с регекспами.

Comment: Кажется. Ну по крайней мере, как это сделать одной регуляркой, мне в голову не приходит. Двумя - как вариант

Comment: Пока самая короткая регулярка - 525 символов. Кто короче?

Comment: 22 символа с двумя просмотрами вперёд. Задача совсем не так проста.

Comment: Лучше вообще никогда (кроме самых очевидных случаев) **не использовать регулярные выражения**. Программы с ними подвержены многочисленным ошибкам, вносимым при последующих модификациях (обычно уже не автором, а другими программистами)

Comment: @avp, я согласен. Но сама задача - огонь!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, согласен. Задачка не тривиальная.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@SwaD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/520560/swad) уже дал нужный ответ, но вот пример проверки, которая проверяет, что введенное значение состоит из 5 цифр и не имеет одинаковых цифр подряд:

```js
function checkNumber(num) {
  const regex = /^(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?!\1|\2)(\d)(?!\1|\2|\3)(\d)(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)\d$/;
  return regex.test(num);
}

console.log(checkNumber('12345')); // true
console.log(checkNumber('223341')); // true
console.log(checkNumber('44441')); // true
console.log(checkNumber('00000')); // false
console.log(checkNumber('11111')); // false
console.log(checkNumber('1234')); // false
console.log(checkNumber('123456')); // false
```

Здесь используется регулярное выражение, которое состоит из:

- `^` - начала строки
- `(\d)` - первая цифра, которая сохраняется в первую группу захвата
- `(?!\1)` - негативный просмотр вперед, чтобы проверить, что следующая цифра не равна первой
- `(\d)` - вторая цифра, которая сохраняется во вторую группу захвата
- `(?!\1|\2)` - негативный просмотр вперед, чтобы проверить, что следующая цифра не равна первой или второй
- `(\d)` - третья цифра, которая сохраняется в третью группу захвата
- `(?!\1|\2|\3)` - негативный просмотр вперед, чтобы проверить, что следующая цифра не равна первой, второй или третьей
- `(\d)` - четвертая цифра, которая сохраняется в четвертую группу захвата
- `(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)` - негативный просмотр вперед, чтобы проверить, что следующая цифра не равна первой, второй, третьей или четвертой
- `\d` - пятая цифра
- `$` - конец строки

Таким образом, регулярное выражение гарантирует, что строка содержит 5 цифр и не имеет одинаковых цифр подряд. Функция `checkNumber` возвращает `true`, если строка соответствует этому шаблону, и `false` в противном случае.

---

Ответ наоборот.

Для проверки наличия 5 цифр без повторения можно использовать следующее регулярное выражение:

```
/^(?!.*(\d)\1)[0-9]{5}$/
```

Данное регулярное выражение состоит из двух частей. Первая часть `^(?!.*(\d)\1)` используется для проверки на повторяющиеся цифры. Она использует негативный просмотр вперед `(?!...)`, который говорит, что далее не должно быть повторяющихся цифр. В данном случае `.*(\d)\1` проверяет, есть ли две одинаковые цифры подряд. Если такие цифры есть, то проверка не пройдет.

Вторая часть `[0-9]{5}$` проверяет, что строка содержит ровно 5 цифр до конца строки.

Таким образом, данное регулярное выражение проверит, что строка состоит из 5 цифр без повторений.
Если нужно проверить число отличное 5 цифр, то укажите другое число. Или же выражение вида `[0-9]{5,10}$`, которе говорит минимум 5 цифр, но максимум 10ю

Comment: `44441` -> `false` в первой программе.

Answer (score 4):

Да, такое регулярное выражение существует. Всего 22 символа, один положительный просмотр вперёд, один отрицательный ([lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions)):

```
  начало строки
  |
  v          запомнить первый символ
  -          ---
 /^(?=\d{5}$)(.)(?!\1*$)/
   ----------   --------
   ^            \1*$    - запомненный символ повторяется до конца строки,
   |            (?!...) - это отрицание, оно сработает если не все
   |                      символы в строке совпадают с первым
   |
   \d{5}$  - ровно пять цифр и конец строки,
   (?=...) - проверка делается, но символы в строке "остаются" -
             остаток выражения снова будет работать с целой строкой
```

Выражение проверяет что

- в строке ровно пять символов,
- все символы цифры,
- строка не состоит из пяти одинаковых цифр.

```js
const re5 = /^(?=\d{5}$)(.)(?!\1*$)/;

console.log(re5.source);
console.log(re5.source.length);

[
    '0000', '0010',
    '00000', '11111', '22222', '33333', '44444', '55555',
    '11112', '11121', '67890',
    '112111', '111111'
].forEach(s => console.log(s, '=>', re5.test(s)));

(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        const s = String(i).padStart(5, '0');
        console.assert(re5.test(s) === (i % 11111 !== 0));
    }
})();
```

Если без просмотров вперёд и назад, то задача тоже разрешима. Всего 525 символов:

```
/^(0(0(0(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)|[1-9]\d\d)|[1-9]\d{3})|1(1(1(1[02-9]|[02-9]\d)|[02-9]\d\d)|[02-9]\d{3})|2(2(2(2[013-9]|[013-9]\d)|[013-9]\d\d)|[013-9]\d{3})|3(3(3(3[0124-9]|[0124-9]\d)|[0124-9]\d\d)|[0124-9]\d{3})|4(4(4(4[0-35-9]|[0-35-9]\d)|[0-35-9]\d\d)|[0-35-9]\d{3})|5(5(5(5[0-46-9]|[0-46-9]\d)|[0-46-9]\d\d)|[0-46-9]\d{3})|6(6(6(6[0-5789]|[0-5789]\d)|[0-5789]\d\d)|[0-5789]\d{3})|7(7(7(7[0-689]|[0-689]\d)|[0-689]\d\d)|[0-689]\d{3})|8(8(8(8[0-79]|[0-79]\d)|[0-79]\d\d)|[0-79]\d{3})|9(9(9(9[0-8]|[0-8]\d)|[0-8]\d\d)|[0-8]\d{3}))$/
```

Тут оно отформатировано, чтобы легче было понять структуру. В работающем выражении не должно быть пробелов и переводов строк:

```
^(
      0 (0 (0 (0[1-9   ] | [1-9   ]\d) | [1-9   ]\d\d) | [1-9   ]\d{3})
    | 1 (1 (1 (1[02-9  ] | [02-9  ]\d) | [02-9  ]\d\d) | [02-9  ]\d{3})
    | 2 (2 (2 (2[013-9 ] | [013-9 ]\d) | [013-9 ]\d\d) | [013-9 ]\d{3})
    | 3 (3 (3 (3[0124-9] | [0124-9]\d) | [0124-9]\d\d) | [0124-9]\d{3})
    | 4 (4 (4 (4[0-35-9] | [0-35-9]\d) | [0-35-9]\d\d) | [0-35-9]\d{3})
    | 5 (5 (5 (5[0-46-9] | [0-46-9]\d) | [0-46-9]\d\d) | [0-46-9]\d{3})
    | 6 (6 (6 (6[0-5789] | [0-5789]\d) | [0-5789]\d\d) | [0-5789]\d{3})
    | 7 (7 (7 (7[0-689 ] | [0-689 ]\d) | [0-689 ]\d\d) | [0-689 ]\d{3})
    | 8 (8 (8 (8[0-79  ] | [0-79  ]\d) | [0-79  ]\d\d) | [0-79  ]\d{3})
    | 9 (9 (9 (9[0-8   ] | [0-8   ]\d) | [0-8   ]\d\d) | [0-8   ]\d{3})
)$
```

Программа ниже генерирует выражение на лету и тестирует его:

```js
const makeRe = n => {
    const without = [
        /* 0 */ '[1-9]'   , /* 1 */ '[02-9]'  ,
        /* 2 */ '[013-9]' , /* 3 */ '[0124-9]',
        /* 4 */ '[0-35-9]', /* 5 */ '[0-46-9]',
        /* 6 */ '[0-5789]', /* 7 */ '[0-689]' ,
        /* 8 */ '[0-79]'  , /* 9 */ '[0-8]'    
    ];

    const all = n => (n < 3) ? '\\d'.repeat(n) : `\\d{${n}}`;

    const or = alternatives => `(${alternatives.join('|')})`;

    const startsFrom = d => {
        //           0[1-9]
        let re = `${d}${without[d]}`;
        for (let i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
            //       0[1-9]                                 ->
            //     0(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)                        ->
            //   0(0(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)|[1-9]\d\d)             ->
            // 0(0(0(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)|[1-9]\d\d)|[1-9]\d{3})
            re = `${d}${or([re, `${without[d]}${all(i - 1)}`])}`;
        }
        return re;
    }

    const union = or([...Array(10).keys()].map(startsFrom));
    return new RegExp(`^${union}$`);
};

const re5 = makeRe(5);

console.log(re5.source);
console.log(re5.source.length);

[
    '0000', '0010',
    '00000', '11111', '22222', '33333', '44444', '55555',
    '11112', '11121', '67890',
    '112111', '111111'
].forEach(s => console.log(s, '=>', re5.test(s)));

(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        const s = String(i).padStart(5, '0');
        console.assert(re5.test(s) === (i % 11111 !== 0));
    }
})();
```

**P.S.** Попробуйте придумать выражение короче. Три требования приведены выше, все должны быть выполнены.

Answer (score 1):

Ну возможно так себе решение, но регулярка одна :)

```js
const arr = [
  '00000',
  '11111',
  '22222',
  '33333',
  '44444',
  '55555',
  '12345',
  '12344',
  '55555',
  '12232',
  '11113',
  '88887'
]

const re = /0{5}|1{5}|2{5}|3{5}|4{5}|5{5}|6{5}|7{5}|8{5}|9{5}/
arr.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item, !re.test(item))
})
```

Comment: Единственное, что она не проверяет `должны проходить 5 цифер`. Если это принципиально автору вопроса, конечно.

Comment: @mironovmeow Ну да, проверку длины не делал, исходя из того, что всего их 5...

Comment: Не цифры тоже буду приняты.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант от [@senior-pomidor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209435/senior-pomidor):

> Для проверки наличия 5 цифр без повторения можно использовать следующее регулярное выражение:

```
/^(?!.*(\d)\1)[0-9]{5}$/
```

Легко переделать под условия задачи:

- Убираем `.*` в негативном просмотре вперед, исключив проверку наличия ноля и более любых символов
- Установим квантификатор на возвращаемую группу в негативном просмотре вперед `{4}`

Итого получаем следующее регулярное выражение:

```
/^(?!(\d)\1{4})\d{5}$/
```

где проверяем что первая захваченная цифра не повторяется четыре раза.

Пример на JS, так как он встраиваемый:

```js
const str = `12345
11223
11111
22222
01234
44441
44444`;
const reg = /^(?!(\d)\1{4})\d{5}$/gm
console.log(str.match(reg));
```

Comment: Мне кажется можно проще проверить именно на ввод пяти одинаковых цифр подряд и выловить ошибочный ввод выражением:  /\b(\d)\1{4}\b/gm - нас же по условию интересует выявление чисел из 5 одинаковых цифр подряд, а \b вполне подойдет для отделения числа, как целого "слова"

Comment: @Дмитрий Хороший пример, но делает ровно противоположное)

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось следующее - `^(?:(\d)(?!.*\1)){5}$`

```js
const regex = /^(?:(\d)(?!.*\1)){5}$/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('^(?:(\\d)(?!.*\\1)){5}$', 'gm')

const str = `12345
76523
17173`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```